# Why did I just get a second Steward badge for the same queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, badges

I just got awarded a [second Steward badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward?userid=3270037) in a queue for which I already had the badge:

[image]

How come?

Comment: That's intentional, you'll get another badge for every 1000 reviews in the queue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360279/steward-badge-can-now-be-awarded-multiple-times-backfill-details

Comment: [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198): "There is more incentive to continue reviewing. The Steward badge can now be earned multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in each queue. If you have already completed 2,000 or more reviews, we will backfill any additional Steward badges that you have already earned. You can expect to see them accrue over the next few days."

Comment: So if I do 100,000 reviews I will get 100 steward badges?

Comment: @10Rep If you do 100,000 reviews in the same queue, yes you would earn 100 Steward badges for that queue.

Comment: So, this is why I suddenly got 15 steward badges?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) and [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times — backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360279/steward-badge-can-now-be-awarded-multiple-times-backfill-details) it is now possible to be awarded with Steward badges multiple times (once per 1,000 reviews).

A backfill script is running which will periodically give Steward badges until you have been awarded all the badges you have earned from reviews.

Comment: That means the badge description should be updated then, «Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. **This badge is awarded once per review type**. This badge can be awarded multiple times.»

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 its been [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360204/347191)